# How to disable submit button if checkbox and dropdown menu wasn't filled yet?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, checkbox

I am using 2 different functions for checkbox and dropdown
Checkbox function:

```
$(function () {
    $('.cb').change(function () {
        if ($(this).is(":checked")) {
            $('#add').removeAttr('disabled');
        }
        else {
            var isChecked = false;
            $('.cb').each(function () {
                if ($(this).is(":checked")) {
                    $('#add').removeAttr('disabled');
                    isChecked = true;
                }
            });
            if (!isChecked) {
                $('#add').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
            }
        }
    })
});
```

Dropdown function:

```
$("#tripSelect").on('change',function(){
   if($(this).find('option:selected').text()=="Choose Trip")
       $("#add").attr('disabled',true)
   else
       $("#add").attr('disabled',false)
});
```

They don't work with each other. I tried combining them but it's not working for me. I wanted to disable the `#add` button if not at least 1 checkbox is checked and the dropwdown says anything but `Choose Trip`. If 1 of the them is false then the button is disabled.

Comment: Consider using `required` attribute on your checkboxes.

Comment: I tried `required` but on `select` but it's not working. I'm not using `type="submit"` by the way. It's just a simple `a href=""` button type

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
$("#tripSelect, .cb").change(function(){
  
  if( $('.cb:checked').length == 0  || $("#tripSelect").val() == "Choose Trip")
  {
    $("#add").attr('disabled',true)
  }
  else
   {
     
   $('#add').removeAttr('disabled');
     
   }
  
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="checkbox" class="cb" id="chckselect">Check Me
<input type="checkbox" class="cb" id="chckselect1">Another check
<select id="tripSelect">
        <option>Choose Trip</option>
        <option>Choose travel</option>
 </select>

<input type="submit" id="add" value="Add" disabled>
```

Comment: The #add button is `enabled` even though the dropdown menu still says `Choose trip`

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```js
$(function () {
var isChecked;
    $('.cb').change(function () {
        $('.cb').each(function () {
                if ($(this).is(":checked")) {
                 
                    isChecked = true;
                }
            });
    });
   $("#tripSelect").on('change',function(){
      if($("#tripSelect option:selected").text()=="Choose Trip" && isChecked==true)
       $("#add").attr('disabled',false)
    else
         $("#add").attr('disabled',true)
});
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="checkbox" class="cb" >isChecked<br><br>
<select id="tripSelect">
 <option>--Select--</option>
<option>Choose Trip</option>

</select>
<input type="button" value="add" id="add" disabled>
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Your code got some bug. The add button is enabled even though it's uncheck after testing them

Comment: if ($(this).is(":checked")) {
                   // $('#add').removeAttr('disabled');
                    isChecked = true;
                     if($("#tripSelect option:selected").text()=="Choose Trip" && isChecked==true)
                      $("#add").attr('disabled',false)
                }
                else{
                  isChecked = false;
                 $("#add").attr('disabled',true)
                }

Answer (score 1):

I Hope This Meets your requirement.

```js
var abc = "";
var cda = "";
 $(document).ready(function(){
  $('#chk, #selVal').change(function(){
   abc = $('#chk').is(':checked');
   cda = $('#selVal').val();
   if(abc == true && cda != "--select--"){
    $('#btn').attr('disabled', false);
    abc = true;    
   }else{
    $('#btn').attr('disabled', true);
    abc= false
   }
  });
 });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
Select : <input type="checkbox" name="chk" id="chk">

 <select id="selVal">
  <option value="--select--">--Select--</option>
  <option value="Two">Two</option>
  <option value="Three">Three</option>
 </select>

 <button id="btn" disabled="true">Hello</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a single event handler. Use `:checked` selector along with `.length`  property to get the no of checked checkboxes  and `.val()` to get value of `select`

```
$(document).on('change',"#tripSelect, .cb", function(){
   $("#add").prop('disabled', $('.cb:checked').length == 0 || $("#tripSelect").find('option:selected').text() == "Choose Trip" )
});
```

Additionally use `.prop()` to set `disabled` property.

```js
$(document).on('change', "#tripSelect, .cb", function() {
  $("#add").prop('disabled', $('.cb:checked').length == 0 || $("#tripSelect").find('option:selected').text() == "Choose Trip")
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="checkbox" class="cb">isChecked
<br>
<br>
<select id="tripSelect">
  <option>Choose Trip</option>
  <option>Choose Trip 1</option>
  <option>Choose Trip 2</option>
</select>
<input type="button" value="add" id="add" disabled>
```

Comment: I really feel bad about this. It's working just fine on the snippet but it's not working when I merge it to my codes

Comment: @Newbie, Did you wrapped the code in `$(function () { .. })`

Comment: yes. The `#add` button is already disabled btw. Maybe that information can help me :)

Answer (score 0):

code updated

```js
$(function () {
var isChecked;
    $('.cb').change(function () {
        $('.cb').each(function () {
                if ($(this).is(":checked")) {
                   // $('#add').removeAttr('disabled');
                    isChecked = true;
                     if($("#tripSelect option:selected").text()=="Choose Trip" && isChecked==true)
                      $("#add").attr('disabled',false)
                }
                else
                 $("#add").attr('disabled',true)

            });
    });
    //drop
   $("#tripSelect").on('change',function(){
      if($("#tripSelect option:selected").text()=="Choose Trip" && isChecked==true)
       $("#add").attr('disabled',false)
    else
         $("#add").attr('disabled',true)
});






});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="checkbox" class="cb" >isChecked<br><br>
<select id="tripSelect">
 <option>--Select--</option>
<option>Choose Trip</option>

</select>
<input type="button" value="add" id="add" disabled>
```